# Only use dnsmasq for specific devices

Tags: ubuntu, domain-name-system, dnsmasq

I have a very simple dnsmasq setup, where the server with dnsmasq is the main DNS server in the network and all requests, except for hosts specified in /etc/hosts, are just passed through.

What I'm trying to do now, is to apply the altered DNS entries from /etc/hosts to devices specified either by IP or MAC (I don't know which of these is possible) only. For example:

`192.168.1.5 google.com` is in the hosts file. Now a device queries the DNS server for google.com and receives the correct IP. Another device with a  static IP or specific MAC address queries the DNS and gets `192.168.1.5` as a reply.

I looked at the documentation for dnsmasq.conf, but couldn't find anything to accomplish this. Do I maybe have to do some iptables stuff, or is this simply not possible?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe `dnsmasq` supports split DNS.  The normal way to do this would be to configure the device that should pass through to use external DNS servers.

`dnsmasq` can be configured to send different hosts different resolver lists via DHCP using tags.  If you aren't using DHCP for the server, configure the server to use external DNS servers.

It seems like you may be configuring a proxy server.  They usually have configure options for the DNS servers the proxy will use.  `dnsmasq` can be used to specify the auto-configuration file that specifies the proxy address.